# What is the best practice for cleaning data after inserting for a unit test

Tags: php, mysql, unit-testing

As the head says, after I inserted some rows (just for testing) to the database in a unit test function, I currently place a query at the end of the function to remove those manually, but I believe that is not the best practice to do.
So what is it?

Comment: Unit tests shouldn't normally interact with genuine services: the usual practice is to *mock* them instead.

Comment: Ruby on Rails uses transactions to roll back changes made during testing.

Comment: Honestly, I prefer interacting with real services, as it's more of an accurate "test" -- and since rolling back transactions only affects auto-increments, and auto-increments should never have any logic applied to them, I rationalize that it's fine to start a transaction, perform a test, and then roll back the transaction at the end of it. Just watch out for SQL queries that break transactions by triggering implicit commits (such as `ALTER`). But while this is what I do, I'm not sure if it's best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when working on Data Fixtures maybe the best option is implementing `setUp()` and `tearDown()` methods.
If you have allocated external resources like files, database or sockets so `tearDown()` method seems the best way to go.

From PHPUnit docs:

> setUp() and tearDown() are nicely symmetrical in theory but not in
>   practice. In practice, you only need to implement tearDown() if you
>   have allocated external resources like files or sockets in setUp(). If
>   your setUp() just creates plain PHP objects, you can generally ignore
>   tearDown(). However, if you create many objects in your setUp(), you
>   might want to unset() the variables pointing to those objects in your
>   tearDown() so they can be garbage collected. The garbage collection of
>   test case objects is not predictable.

You can get more info Data Fixtures in [Chapter 4. Fixtures](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html):

Answer (score 0):

"Best practice" is always a subjective request. It's probably not best practice to use real services, but I do, because realistically it's what I feel works best for me. By using real services, I'm actually testing against all sorts of database-specific minutia (such as foreign key constraints, triggers, etc).

You could create a database transaction, perform your SQL queries, and then rollback the transaction. But in order to do this, you need two assumptions:

- That you're not implying any logic from auto-increment fields (as you should already be doing, anyway)
- That you're not performing SQL queries within the scope of a transaction that perform implicit commits. Implicit commits cannot be rolled back.

Implicit commits for MySQL are, [according to its documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html), as follows:

> 'ALTER TABLE',
> 'CREATE INDEX',
> 'DROP INDEX',
> 'DROP TABLE',
> 'RENAME TABLE',
> 'CREATE TABLE',
> 'CREATE DATABASE',
> 'DROP DATABASE',
> 'TRUNCATE TABLE',
> 'ALTER PROCEDURE',
> 'CREATE PROCEDURE',
> 'DROP PROCEDURE',
> 'ALTER FUNCTION',
> 'CREATE FUNCTION',
> 'DROP FUNCTION',
> 'ALTER VIEW',
> 'CREATE TRIGGER',
> 'CREATE VIEW',
> 'DROP TRIGGER',
> 'DROP VIEW',
> 'CREATE USER',
> 'DROP USER',
> 'RENAME USER'